# Git Configuration User Settings "Add Entry Button" is disabled

Tags: git, eclipse, configuration, settings

When I want to add user and email for git staging checkin through "Git Configuration User Settings", *Add Entry* button is disabled. Also I can not reach `S:\` folder and can not change the gitconfig file location.

The command which is in the below can change the email adress project by project. But I want to change the email for all repository's projects.

```
git config --global user.email "OUR_NAME@example.com"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is given in the screenshot above as `S:\.gitconfig (non-writeable)`:

**No file permissions** to **write** into the file **`S:\.gitconfig`** (where these entries are stored) at least not for the user on which Eclipse runs.