# Eclipse 2022-03. Change directory path user settings Git configuration

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, egit

I have installed eclipse-2022-03 and the config path appears as U:\gitconfig (non-writable)
I have seen that in other questions, they claim that the button appears disabled and does not allow adding configuration and that the problem is due to the route that I mentioned.
Some get the drive letter S and I get the drive letter U. I don't have that drive defined on my computer, so I think it's a random issue with the plugin.
I also have CodeReady Studio installed and it is the same situation.
I installed eclipse-2022-03 today and there is the same problem as in 2020-12.
Is there any way to solve this?

[Git Configuration User Settings "Add Entry Button" is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890081/git-configuration-user-settings-add-entry-button-is-disabled)

Plugin version in 2022-03:
[image]

Plugin version in CodeReady Studio:
[image]

I have seen the problem since I am generating a configuration server with spring boot and I need to have the properties in the repository, when making the request to obtain the properties, it generates an error that does not allow it to create a temporary file since it tries to search in the U disk.

Eclipse 2022-03
[image]

CodeReady Studio
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does setting the `HOME` environment variable fix your issue? https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/

Comment: It work!!!
Thansk!

Comment: I think this should be automatic. If that environment variable does not exist, use the home of the user who is installing the IDE.

Comment: JGit/EGit mimic the behavior of the command line Git which also applies for [`HOME`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables). I'm not sure if in your case ( `HOME` not set and Eclipse installed on a different drive than the Windows user profile with which Eclipse is running?), it's the intended behavior or a bug.

Comment: I've installed by default eclipse without change on C unit. It's found on my user profile.
It true that I not had HOME enviroment variable and I've created it.
Thanks a lot!